# babel [...] --watch not working for building an es6 folder every time there is a change

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs, babel-cli

I am creating a simple component library and would like to have it built every time I save one of my files.

This is what my current command looks like:

```
"watch": "babel components/ --out-dir dist --copy-files --ignore test.js --watch"
```

I have also moved the `--watch` flag around to see if it would make a difference and so far it does not make a difference and it only runs once.

For what it's worth, I am using `@babel/cli v7.8.4`. Anyway how could I get it to build every time I make a change? If so, what is wrong with my command?

Comment: can u check ur node js version. it is working fine for me. Try clean `npm clean-install ` or rm -rf ~/.npm

Comment: Node version is `v10.17.0`. Will give your suggestions a try.

Answer (score 2):

try follow:

"watch": "babel components --extensions .jsx --out-dir dist --copy-files --ignore test.js --watch"